# Runtime value population in Struts 2 textfield

Tags: java, jsp, struts2, jstl, ognl

I need to show list of text fields where number of textfields will be equal to number of element in the map and label should be key of the entry and value of textfield should be value corresponding to the key.

I attempted something like this:

```
<c:forEach var="score" items="${result.examscore}">
    <s:textfield label="%{score.key}" value="%{score.value}"></s:textfield>
</c:forEach>
```

I checked this code by hardcoding label and value's value. So, iteration is working fine, it is just a matter of populating values in textfields.

Comment: Personally, I'd probably use `<s:iterator>` here if you're dealing solely with S2 data, instead of mixing and matching taglibs.

Comment: Yes, i also think `<s:iterator>` will be nice choice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The variable `score` is not available in the value stack. Try

```
<s:textfield label="%{#attr.score.key}" value="%{#attr.score.value}"></s:textfield>
```

Comment: Bang on!!! Thanks a lot. It would be nice if you can tell me that where `score` was stored and how `#attr` is looking at that location.

Comment: It's in the page scope, and `#attr` is searching in all scopes.